# Learning Locker xAPI returns unauthorised message when sending statement for valid credentials

Tags: xapi, learning-locker

Having set up a Client in Learning Locker and tested then tested xAPI with an about call, it returned the basic information.

However, when I sent the xAPI a statement, instead it returned "unauthorised."
[image: p]

I'm sure that the credentials are correct.  Is there something else I need to set?

Answer (score 0):

The message had nothing to do with "authorisation."  Instead, it was caused by not setting up the "Store" correctly and then referencing it in the associated Client.

Watch the following video to catch all of the steps.

[YOUTUBE: How to Use Clients & Stores in Learning Locker - HT2 Labs](https://youtu.be/KSpT7F9YRKw)